# Not counting duplicate data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I need a querybuilder query that calculates how many different people the user is messaging without counting the repetitive data.

[database photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaUht.png)

Example:

```
conver_user_id = 165, conver_user_seller_id = 156
conver_user_id = 165, conver_user_seller_id = 156
conver_user_id = 165, conver_user_seller_id = 156
conver_user_id = 165, conver_user_seller_id = 158
conver_user_id = 165, conver_user_seller_id = 158

the result i want : Total count: 2
```

I will be glad if you help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the user when the query is executed, as you ask "the user is messaging". Using group by, to select the unique conversations, then counting it.

```
$uniqueSellersMessaging = Conversation::where('conver_user_id', $user->id)
    ->groupBy('conver_user_seller_id')
    ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `distinct` method on the query builder to achieve the desired result.

```php
$total_count = DB::table('conversations')
    ->where('conver_user_id', $user_id)
    ->select('conver_user_seller_id')
    ->distinct()
    ->count();
```